# Issue in ParamQuery Grid Inline Edit

Tags: grid

We are using ParamQuery grid in our project.
In one of our screen, we are using the grid in modal popup with inline edit feature.

We are facing issue on editing the cell from second time. Here are the steps followed,

1. Open the popup, first time, tried to edit a record – it is perfectly changed and updated.
2. Now close and re-open the modal popup.
3. Try to change the data and update - It is not updating any data. Changed data gets vanished by retaining the previous value.
4. On debugging the code,

a.  We are getting false in the following code snippet while updating the data,

```html
 if (grid.saveEditCell() == false) {
        return false;
  }
```

b.  We are also getting the script error,

```html
pqgrid.min.js:188 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined(…)
```

As of now, we are using the workaround,

“After updating the data 1st time, we are re-loading (using window.location.reload()) the page. Now it is working correctly. But in Ajax world, we don’t want to reload the full page, just to solve this issue. We believe, that this is because of some small issue or configuration missing.”
Referred the following article and implemented the inline edit functionality http://paramquery.com/pro/demos/editing 
Appreciate your help.